# MYSQL : secure-file-priv

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, null, set

Is there any query that I can set this variable to null in console tap of phpmyadmin panel?

I tackle to bellow error code from mysql when I want to execute some php code through the query.

ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Comment: I don't think this option can be changed on the fly, it has to be set when the server starts, either in `mysql.conf` or a command line option.

Comment: This setting is NOT dynamic. It cannot be changed without MySQl server restart.